# If the user is logged in?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I'm new to react so my question may seem obvious.

What is the secure way of rendering certain things if the user is logged in?

Lets just say for example a person logs in so he sees a button to edit his bank details.

If I were to write a javascript script that executes showing the button if the person is logged in that seems like it could be hacked, by a hacker simply modifying the code to escape the check.

Comment: They shouldn't be able to escape the checks by modifying stuff on the frontend. Your validations should be done in the backend as well. Rendered page can always be tweaked, e.g., I can just copy paste the gmail `html` when I'm logged in, in a brand new session, however any `http` requests I'd try from that view wouldn't work. You can take a look at strategies like `jwt`. Or you can take a look at serverside-rendered react frameworks like Nextjs.

Comment: Check out `React.useContext`. You can store the user's logged-in state in the context and only allow access to the sensitive information if the context contains a logged-in state. As for the hacker issue, anybody can be hacked, just focus on securing your authentication process (i.e. logging in)